# Toolbar SF informs client than user is authenticated?

Tags: symfony

Toolbar SF informs client that user is authenticated. Despite being disconnected, the toolbar still represents a user authenticated (authenticated => yes).

Any one help me?

Comment: You can be authenticated like Anonymous but without more informations it's difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the Symfony documentation for the [Security Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html). It clearly states that when you allow anonymous access that the authentication => yes is merely stating that an anonymous user is being used.

> In fact, if you go to the homepage right now, you'll have access and you'll see that you're "authenticated" as anon.. Don't be fooled by the "Yes" next to Authenticated, you're just an anonymous user (Quoted 5/27/2018)

If you follow the rest of the documentation you should be able to figure out how to only allow legitimate non-anonymous users to access the page.